# How implement inline Add new row, Edit and Delete row with REST call using MaterialTable in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using MaterialTable in my application i am struggling to implement REST .
Add new row Update row and Delete row.
I am using MaterialTable editable . How i will do rest calls ? 
bellow i mentioned material table  that i am using

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-41123

https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable

```
this.setState = {
columns: [
                { title: 'User Name', field: 'username',lookup : {2: 'shubham', 3:'timmmmyyy',4 :'Mehmet',5:'Zerya Betül'} },
                { title: 'Role',
                    field: 'roles',
                    lookup: { 34: 'Primary', 63: 'Secondary' ,53 : 'Escallation', 54:'Override ' },
                  },

                { title: 'Start Date', field: 'Startdate', type: 'datetime' },
                { title: 'End Date', field: 'enddate', type: 'datetime' },


            ],
}


 <MaterialTable   
                        title = ""
                        columns={this.state.columns}

                        data = {this.state.data}

                        editable={{
                            onRowAdd: newData =>
                            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                              setTimeout(() => {
                                {
                                  const data = this.state.data;
                                  data.push(newData);
                                  this.setState({ data }, () => resolve());
                                }
                                resolve()
                              }, 1000)
                            }),
                            onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    {
                                    const data = this.state.data;
                                    const index = data.indexOf(oldData);
                                    data[index] = newData;
                                    this.setState({ data }, () => resolve());
                                    }
                                    resolve()
                                }, 1000)
                                }),
                            onRowDelete: oldData =>
                                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    {
                                    let data = this.state.data;
                                    const index = data.indexOf(oldData);
                                    data.splice(index, 1);
                                    this.setState({ data }, () => resolve());
                                    }
                                    resolve()
                                }, 1000)
                                }),    
                          }}
                          options ={{
                            actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                          }}
                    />
```

I want to implement REST in inline table using MaterialTable.

Thanks

Comment: i think you should open github issue on their repo, as even their original example has same issue, `edit` doesn't work.

Comment: Posted but no response